# How to show that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is countable by bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb Z$ be the set of non-negative integers (i.e. including $0$). Show that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is countable by constructing the actual bijection $f \colon \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to {\mathbb N}$ (where ${\mathbb N}$ is the set of all natural numbers). You do not have to prove that it is a bijection.

I've tried the cantor diagonal rule, but I'm getting confused when going from two dimensional to three dimensional.

Comment: Your notation is weird/funny. Normally ${\mathbb Z}$ denotes the set of all integers and ${\mathbb N}$ denotes the set of natural number. Whether or not ${\mathbb N}$ contains $0$ is up for discussion.

Comment: Since no one else has explained it... You're getting downvotes because you haven't shown effort. The users here are concerned about this turning into a homework forum, so you're supposed to write down what you've attempted, instead of copy-pasting the question.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the cantor diagonal rule, but I'm getting confused when going from two dimensional to three dimensional.

Comment: @PyRules Likely, the OP doesn't consider $Z$ and ${\mathbb N}$ the same, otherwise he'd have used the same symbol for them. Anyway, that's an interpretation only the OP should make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your favorite bijection $g \colon Z \to {\mathbb N}$. Also take your favorite bijection $h \colon {\mathbb N}^2 \to {\mathbb N}$. Now take
$$f \colon Z^3 \to {\mathbb N} \qquad f(x,y,z) = h(h(g(x), g(y)), g(z)).$$